# Permissions in SQL Server based upon the content of a row

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `(MainTable)`, each row contains data for a civil engineering project and the county where the project is located.  The DB users, engineers, have been assigned a set of counties in New York State (NYS), this relationship is established by another table `(EngineerCountyTable)`. When MainTable must be updated these are the rules:

- I do not want an engineer to be updating data for a project located
  in a county, which has not been assigned to him. I want all
  the engineers.
- Engineers can see all projects regardless of the county where the
  project is located.

Is there any way to assign permissions in SQL Server based upon the content a row (County in this case)? Thanks

Comment: Sounds like [Row-Level Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security) to me, maybe?

Comment: Sounds like row-level security. Although to be honest, users should be going through an application anyway

Comment: You can use `BLOCK PREDICATE` to block updates https://www.databasejournal.com/ms-sql/row-level-security-with-sql-server-2016-part-2-blocking-updates-at-the-row-level/